# Unable to use ReactiveUI

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal, reactiveui, reactive-property

I've developed a UWP and would like to use ReactiveUI but it introduces incompatibility when I install the 7.4.0 Nuget package. I target Universal Windows Anniversary edition and get the following when I build:

> Error CS0433   The type 'Unit' exists in both 'System.Reactive.Core,
>   Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and
>   'System.Reactive.Core, Version=3.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263'

The same messages appear for a variety of types *Disposable. The 2.2.5.0 version is in .nuget\packages\Rx-Core\2.2.5\lib\windows8\System.Reactive.Core.dll and the 3.0.4000.0 version is in .nuget\packages\System.Reactive.Core\3.1.1\lib\uap10.0\System.Reactive.Core.dll.

When I uninstalled ReactiveUI most of the dependencies had a 2.2.5 suffix. I also have ReactiveProperty 3.6.0 installed that seems to be the source of the incompatibility. I uninstalled ReactiveProperty and kept ReactiveUI but got errors on references to ReactiveProperty.

Is there no way or combination of versions by which I can use both ReactiveUI and ReactiveProperty? Specifically, with just ReactiveProperty I am unable to create an observable with WhenAny as like this:

```
    var canClickMeObservable = this.WhenAny(vm => vm.SomeText, 
        s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.Value));

    ClickMe = new ReactiveCommand(canClickMeObservable);
```

...as described here: http://jen20.com/blog/2013/05/30/reactive-ui-part-3-commands/

Hopefully, there is a way for me to use ReactiveUI and there is some obvious error and bonehead mistake...Anyone? Many thanks for your thoughts..

Comment: Can you please share your packages.json/packages.config/csproj project definitions. It looks like you are referencing Rx3.0 and Rx2.x in the same project. ReactiveUI has a Rx3.0 alpha builds available on our MyGet feed.

Comment: My pleasure and thanks! I'm relatively new to UWP and ReactiveUI so I'll not discount missing some subtlety. I have an app and a library. I wasn't sure of where packages.json and package.config reside so I added the csproj and project.json files for each project. I can get the rest if you can let me know the paths. Here's the link to the Onedrive folder:

[link](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AjRh-3HJOTBOhPhEJsTd5Mfs3_Qu9A)

Comment: I had expected ReactiveProperty to be in ReactiveUI and had seen some guidance on adding them both together somewhere. Maybe they are completely independent projects but it's likely that people will want to sue both. I used solution nugget dialog to install latest versions of each, already indicated. You'll get the 3.6.0 and 7.4.0 respectively.

Comment: Thanks anyway, Geoffrey. I decided not to use Reactive UI even though it looked like it had some potential. I may return to it someday when things get smoothed out a bit. However, someone else may benefit from a response.